# Double Click Listbox to open a new form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Below is my code.

```
Private Sub List27_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strCriteria As String


 DoCmd.OpenForm "PopUp", acNormal, , "[Item (Part) w/ Demand Status Link] = " & Me.List27.Column(0)


End Sub
```

I am able to double click my list box and go to a new pop up form. But I cant get the item i want to show on the form. My list box has 3 columns. I want to double click on of the item in column 1 to show the data on the new popup form.

Thanks.

How do i add an additional where statement for example the code below is not working for me.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "PopUp", acNormal, , "[Item (Part) w/ Demand Status Link] = '" & Me!List27.Column(0) & "'" & "" & "[Line No#] = '" & Me!List27.Column(2) & "'" I'm not getting that to work for me
```

Comment: Is the item in column(0) a number or text?   You can try (shortened your variable for this example)  `"[Item] = '" & me!List27.column(0) & "'"`   Also, I think Column(0) is default, so you can probably get by with `Me!List27` and it should return the first column.

Comment: ...or the bound column

Comment: thanks it work perfectly DoCmd.OpenForm "PopUp", acNormal, , "[Item (Part) w/ Demand Status Link] = '" & Me!List27.Column(0) & "'"

Comment: How do I edit it to add a another where value for example  DoCmd.OpenForm "PopUp", acNormal, , "[Item (Part) w/ Demand Status Link] = '" & Me!List27.Column(0) & "'" & "" & "[Line No#] = '" & Me!List27.Column(2) & "'" I'm not getting that to work for me. @geeflo

Comment: You need to keep your text string in quotes and the & are used outside of the string so you can concatenate the variables into the string.  `"[Item (Part) w/ Demand Status Link] = '" & Me!List27.Column(0) & "'" AND [Line No#] = '" & Me!List27.Column(2) & "'" `